# OwlCarousel 2 - Carousel do not slide by "page" when touch / mouse dragging

Tags: jquery, touch, drag, slide, owl-carousel-2

I've setup my carousel so that my carousel slides by "page" when clicking on navigation arrows, by setting this option: `slideBy: 'page'`. I expected the carousel to also slide by page when touch / mouse dragging, but it only slide my items 1 by 1.

What is the right configuration to make it slide by page on touch / mouse dragging ?

Here is my current configuration:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: false,
    navText: false,
    navSpeed: 200,
    dots: false,
    dotsSpeed: 800,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1,
            slideBy: 'page'
        },
        320: {
            items: 2,
            slideBy: 'page'
        },
        768: {
            items: 4,
            slideBy: 'page'
        },
        992: {
            items: 6,
            slideBy: 'page'
        }
    },
    slideBy: 'page',
    lazyLoad: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may save index of current item before dragging, restore it after dragging and use `next` or `prev` methods from Owl class.
You may find the example in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ay4chvb/).

```
// Empty object where we can store current item's index before drag
var transient = {};

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    slideBy: 'page',
    onDrag: onDrag.bind(transient),
    onDragged: onDragged.bind(transient)
});

function onDrag(event) {
  this.initialCurrent = event.relatedTarget.current();
}

function onDragged(event) {
  var owl = event.relatedTarget;
  var draggedCurrent = owl.current();

  if (draggedCurrent > this.initialCurrent) {
    owl.current(this.initialCurrent);
    owl.next();
  } else if (draggedCurrent < this.initialCurrent) {
    owl.current(this.initialCurrent);
    owl.prev();
  }
}
```